# Using python script to send GET request to a server with netcat

Tags: python, get, netcat

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to write a python script that makes a GET request to a specified image file given the url. As an example, in the code below:

`host` is `www.google.com`

`port` is `80`

`u.path` is `/images/srpr/logo3w.png`

```
proc = Popen(["netcat {} {}".format(host, port)], shell= True)
proc = Popen(["GET {} HTTP/1.1".format(u.path)], shell= True)
proc = Popen(["Host: {}".format(host)], shell= True)
proc = Popen(["Connection: close"], shell= True)
proc = Popen(["\n"], shell= True)
```

My problem is that I can execute these normally in the terminal, but when I try to run the script it seems like sends the `GET` request to `www.google.com` before it takes the specification of `u.path`. I know it is doing this for two reasons. First, just before the server response comes in I get the following:

`/bin/sh: 1: Host:: not found
 /bin/sh: 1: Connection:: not found`

Second, I know that the server response of the image data is a bunch of ugly stuff interpreted as weird Unicode symbols on the terminal, but I'm clearly getting the `www.google.com` HTML text on the server response.

I was thinking I may need to make it wait to do the HTTP request until the `netcat` STDIN is open, but I don't know how. Or maybe it's just completing the request because it's sending a `\n` somehow? I really don't know.

EDIT: It seems like it actually isn't sending the request to `www.google.com`. I saved the server response as a `.html` file and it looks like a cloudfront website

EDIT2: After more research, it seems as if the problem is that since netcat is interactive and so it 'deadlocks' or something like that. I tried to use `proc.communicate()` but since I need to send multiple lines it doesn't allow it seeing as `communicate` only allows the initial input to be written to `STDIN` and then it sends `EOF` or something along those lines. This led me to trying to use `proc.stdin.write` but this is apparently also known to cause deadlock with something related to making the `Popen` commands use `subprocess.PIPE` for `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR`. It also requires the input to be encoded as a  `bytes-like` object, which I have done but when I send `\r\n\r\n` at the end to try to close the connection it doesn't do anything and the `STDOUT` just contains `b''` which I understand to be an empty string in the form of `bytes`

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `netcat` to do a GET request? There many more simple ways to do that.

Comment: This is part of an assignment for a networking class, and we have to use `netcat` only. No libraries or anything that can hide stuff going on in the background.

Comment: Try doing the GET opposite a site other than google.com. Google may object to your robot script getting their data without using their API.

Comment: @boardrider I just did, and I get the same exact results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that has a similar problem, here is the solution that I found:

```
#begin the interactive shell of netcat
proc = Popen(['netcat -q -1 {} {}'.format(host, port)], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

#set file status flags on stdout to non-blocking reads
fcntl.fcntl(proc.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)

#each time we write a diffrent line to the interactive shell
#we need to flush the buffer just to be safe
#credit to http://nigelarmstrong.me/2015/04/python-subprocess/
proc.stdin.write(str.encode('GET %s HTTP/1.1\n' %(path+filename)))
proc.stdin.flush()
proc.stdin.write(str.encode('Host: {}\n'.format(host)))
proc.stdin.flush()
proc.stdin.write(str.encode('Connection: close\n'))
proc.stdin.flush()
proc.stdin.write(str.encode('\r\n\r\n'))
proc.stdin.flush()

#give the server time to respond
proc.wait()

#store the server response (which is bytes-like)
#attempting to decode it results in error since we're recieving data as a mix of text/image
serv_response = proc.stdout.read()
```